# VisualStudio 2017 for Mac - iOS Simulator Starts but Does Not Run the App

Tags: ios, visual-studio, xamarin.ios, ios-simulator, monogame

I have a MonoGame application for iOS and I want to try it with the iPhone Simulator.

When I run the application from Visual Studio for Mac 2017 (I've also tried Visual Studio for Mac 2019... but the result is the same), the iPhone Simulator starts successfully but it doesn't run my application, i.e. it just shows the standard apps like calendar, mail, news, etc.

Any help would be really appreciated :-)

Comment: you need to look at the logs in the output windows to see if there is any useful information

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that my application was build as a 32-bit executable whereas the iPhone Simulator is a 64-bit application. Specifying the appropriate build options fixed the issue.